# Improve code with a Promise for a mongodb request

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, es6-promise

I'm new to javascript (and coding) and I'm looking into Promises.

I have the following working code:

```
router.get("/test", function(req, res){

    var mainCategory = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        Maincategory.find().populate("subcategory").exec(function(err, allMaincategories){
            if (err) {
                console.log("error 1");
                reject("error 2");
            }
            else {
                resolve(allMaincategories);
            }
        });
    });

    var itemQuery = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        Items.find({}, function(err, allItems){
            if (err) {
                console.log("error 3");
                reject("error 4");}
            else {
            resolve(allItems);
            reject("error 5");
            }
        });
    });

    Promise.all([
        mainCategory,
        itemQuery
    ]).then(function(allQueries){
        console.log(allQueries);
        var allCategories = allQueries[0];
        var allItems = allQueries[1]
        var userId = "true";
        var show = "list";
        res.render("test.ejs", {
            allCategories: allCategories, 
            allItems: allItems,
            userId: userId,
            show: show
        });
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("error 6");
        res.render("error.ejs", {error: error});
    });
});
```

Question 1: Is it correct to use a callback inside a promise like that?

Question 2: Is there a (shorter) way to put all mongoose requests in one promise?

Comment: Mongoose already returns promises: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose queries return Promises already - since you're using Promises, better to just *use the Promise* it returns rather than to construct a new one to use with the callback:

```
Promise.all([
  Maincategory.find().populate("subcategory").exec(),
  Items.find({})
]).then(function(allQueries){
  // ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I thought that there would be a shorter way. Thx for your help. That was exaclty what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

mongoose already supports promises natively, so there's no reason at all to create a promise like you are doing. This:

```
var mainCategory = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    Maincategory.find().populate("subcategory").exec(function(err, allMaincategories){
        if (err) {
            console.log("error 1");
            reject("error 2");
        }
        else {
            resolve(allMaincategories);
        }
    });
});
```

should be replaced with

```
const subcatPromise = Maincategory.find().populate("subcategory").exec();
```

and

```
var itemQuery = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    Items.find({}, function(err, allItems){
        if (err) {
            console.log("error 3");
            reject("error 4");}
        else {
        resolve(allItems);
        reject("error 5");
        }
    });
});
```

is equivalent to

```
const itemsPromise = Items.find({});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreaciate a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get("/test", async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const allQueries = await Promise.all([Maincategory.find().populate("subcategory").exec(), Items.find({}).exec()]),
            allCategories = allQueries[0],
            allItems = allQueries[1],
            userId = "true",
            show = "list";
        res.render("test.ejs", {
            allCategories: allCategories,
            allItems: allItems,
            userId: userId,
            show: show
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error 6");
        res.render("error.ejs", {
            error: error
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Ah I understand now, how I can string together two or more queries. Thx for you help.